# Python encoding error " Non-ASCII character '\xff' ..." allthough coding is declared as "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" while writing Hiragana

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, ascii, kana

I'm new to python and I'm getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xff' in file 'hiragana.py' on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
hiragana_map = {"A":u"あ","I":u"い","U":u"う","E":u"え","O":u"お"}
```

I tried it without the u's aswell. It doesn't make a difference.
I'm using the Pycharm communitiy edition. In the encoding settings it says the file is encoded with UTF-16LE.

I'd appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't support source files encoded with with a fixed-width multi-byte codec such as UTF-16 or UTF-32.

Your file is encoded as UTF-16 Little Endian, which means the file starts with a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark); the first two bytes in the file are (hex) FF and FE. Python trips over the first byte.

Re-save the file as UTF-8 instead. See the PyCharm documentation, there is a [section on changing the encoding](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-individual-file-encoding.html#dynaProc1).

Comment: Thanks for figuring this one out for me. Everything works fine.